# How to send a push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

What is a service that i can use to send a notification to an Android device? I want it so i can send it in real time!

Comment: You have to use GCM - Google cloud messaging for sending push notifications to Device. Refer to demo application given in android developer site. [**GCM Demo Application**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html) And main link is - [**Google Cloud Messaging for Android**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: You have to use GCM - Google cloud messaging for sending push notifications to Device. Refer to demo application given in android developer site. [**GCM Demo Application**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html) And main link is - [**Google Cloud Messaging for Android**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: This question being closed basically sums up everything that's wrong with stackoverflow and why I barely use it anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to send notifications in Android is FCM(Firebase cloud message ), and this service is also from google which is a replacement for GCM.Use the below link for more information.

https://firebase.google.com

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion [Firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is the best option. Because [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) has several advantages over GCM.

Firebase Cloud Platform inherits GCM's core infrastructure but simplifies the client development.

**In FCM you do not need to write your own registration or subscription retry logic**. Now, you can integrate FCM in your app with just a few lines of code.

<strike>However, GCM is not deprecated: Google will continue to support it but **all new client-side features will be available on FCM SDK only**. The protocol remains the same server-side though.</strike>

**Update (30 - July - 2018):** As of April 10, 2018, [Google has deprecated GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm). The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. See this [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) to learn more.

Thanks @eis for your comment to update this post.

Comment: "As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the migration guide to learn more." ([source](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm))

Answer (score 0):

I think [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) is the way to go.