# [Q]Javascript send push notifications to android with firebase using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, push, send

i have project android (ex: abc.com.123)
i singed FCM and add project android.
I want setup to send push notifications to all android device (instaled my app) with firebase CM **using Javascript code** 
help me
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385168/how-to-send-a-push-notification)

Comment: i want send from web using Javascript code

Comment: This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple) explains how to send post requests to do that, you can do it via javascript